# Application of Givens rotation to two matrices

Tags: correlation, algorithms, matrix, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse

I am reading this paper on Multiresolution Matrix Fatorization, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.04396v1.pdf, and have come across something that seems like an error to me.  In Algorithm 2, the authors take $A \in R^{n\text{x}c}$ and $A^TA = G \in R^{c\text{x}c}$ and apply a Givens rotation, $q_s$, to both in the following way:

$A \leftarrow q_sAq_s^T$

$G \leftarrow q_sGq_s^T$

This doesn't seem to be correct given the different number rows of $A$ and $G$.  How can the same rotation be applied to both of these matrices?

Comment: On p. 2, immediately before equation (1) and the subsequent introduction of Givens rotations, the paper states $\mathbb{A}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, not $n\times c$.  Could you therefore be more specific about where in the paper these expressions appear?

Comment: I state in the question that they appear in Algorithm 2.

Comment: Thank you--obviously I overlooked that.  The text surrounding the statement of the algorithm appears to explain what's going on--although I agree it's strange to see a mathematically undefined operation appearing in the algorithm itself.  The key to understanding may be in this passage at the beginning of section 2.1: "only consider rotations between $k$-sets of rows/columns that belong to the same cluster."

Comment: So, for Algorithm 2, this would imply that only rotations between pairs of columns are considered, which is clear from the algorithm, but doesn't really address my issue.  A thought I've had is that the $c$x$c$ rotations are applied to all $c$x$c$ blocks in the $n$x$c$ matrix $A$.  This is consistent with what's done in Algorithm 1, where each rotation is applied to every $c$x$c$ block of the $n$x$n$ matrix $A_p$.  Does it make sense to do this in Algorithm 2?